# How to Get Element From Path Not Class or Id

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors

I am struggling to find an answer for this, I want a way to talk about an element, but because of the system I am adding to I do can not reference by its Id as it is dynamic. I can specify the class name of its containing div though... In essence what I am looking for is something along the lines of:

```
var disAb=document.getElementBySomething("div.ContainerDiv select")
```

When I mention the term 'path' I mean how I would reference it in CSS (see code reference).

Thank you guys!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll

Comment: document.querySelector[All]()

Comment: Thanks guys, its all about having the knowledge of where to look heh..? but can I do - querySelector(div.ContainerDiv td tr p)? or just querySelector(div.containerDiv)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You want [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), then just reference it by its hierarchy path:

**Sample HTML**

```
<div class="ContainerDiv">
   <table>
   <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
           <select>
              <option>Some options</option>
           </select>
        </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

**JS**

Get single element

```
var select=document.querySelector("div.ContainerDiv table tr td div select");
select.id = "someid";
```

For more than one element

```
var selects=document.querySelectorAll("div.ContainerDiv select");
selects[0].id = "someid";
```

Of course you do not need each part of the hiearchy, for instance you could just use: `div.ContainerDiv select` or `div.ContainerDiv table select` etc.

Comment: i am getting error `Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...).click is not a function`

Comment: @prabhav Do you mean `querySelectorAll().click is not a function` as `querySelector` only returns the dom element or `null` and if it returned `null` you would have a different error message. If you did mean `querySelectorAll` it is because that returns a collection (wither or not any element is found) and it does not have a `click` method, you would need to access the individual items in the collection to access their `click` method, eg `querySelectorAll(...)[1].click()`

Comment: no i just used `document.querySelector(...).click ` and that is the error message i got from i just copy paste the error